# For discrete $X_n$ if $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} U$, does $P_e \to 1$ where $P_e$ is optimal Bayes error and $U$ is uniform

Tags: maximum-likelihood, signal-detection, map-estimation

Consider the following setting.  Let $ \{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq [-1,1] $ be a **discrete** random variables that converges to a continuous uniform random variable in distribution.

Let $Y_n = X_n +Z_n$ where $Z_n$ is standard normal independent of $X_n$.
Because $X_n$ is discrete the maximum aposteriry estimator of $X_n$ from observation $Y_n$ is given by
\begin{align}
\widehat{X}_n = \arg \max_{x} p_{X_n|Y_n}(x|Y_n)
\end{align}
where is $p_{X_n|Y_n}$ is the conditional pmf of $X_n$ given $Y_n$.  The probability of error for this is define as
\begin{align}
P_{n}^{(e)}= \mathbb{P} [\widehat{X}_n \neq X_n]
\end{align}

**My question:** Can we show that $P_e = \lim_{n \to \infty} P_{n}^{(e)} = 1$?

For the upper bound, we can use a suboptimal estimator that randomly choose one of the support points of $X_n$, which implies that
\begin{align}
P_e  \le 1 - \max_{x} p_{X_n}(x)
\end{align}
Clearly the upper bound converges to $1$. I was not able to think of a good lower bound.

Comment: I think you want the Neyman-Pearson bound on distinguishing two nearby possible values of $X_n$

Comment: I guess you mean $P_e=\lim_{n\to\infty} P_n^{(e)}$?

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thanks. Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: @ThomasLumley Could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the mapping from the variable $Y_n$ to  the estimates $\hat{X}_n = f(Y_n)$. The probability to estimate correctly will depend on the true value of $X_n$

$$P(\hat{X}_n = X_n | X_n) = P(f(Y_n+X_n) = X_n)$$

For some values $X_n$ these probabilities can have a lower bound above zero.

For example, if we have consider a set of equidistant values $x = \lbrace -1, -1+d, -1+2d, \dots, 1 \rbrace$, then if the true value is $X_n = -1$ or $X_n = 1$, then the probability of estimating correct will be approaching 0.5 (namely if $Z_n <0$ for $X_n = -1$ and $Z_n > 0$ for $X_n = 1$, which happens with 0.5 probability, then the estimate will be correct).

However, despite that we have these lower bound with some values of $X_n$, if we consider an average of guessing correct, then we need to use

$$P(\hat{X}_n = X_n) = \sum_{\forall x} P(\hat{X}_n = X_n | X_n = x) P(\hat{X}_n = x)$$

This average should approach zero when we keep adding numbers.

At least for the example with the distribution being an equidistant set of equally probable values, case we can show this. For the values on the edges, the probability $P(\hat{X}_n = X_n | X_n = x)$ approaches 0.5, but for the other values it approaches zero.

Below we show an image related to the example above.

[image: example of decreasing region when n increases]

The points in the image are thousand points sampled as

$$\begin{array}{}
X_n &\sim& \text{discrete uniform from -1 to 1} \\
Z_n &\sim& N(0,1) \\
Y_n &:=& X_n+Z_n\end{array}$$

in the background of the scatterplot  we show a blue region where the estimates are correct.

<sup>For the example this is a simple region, for other discrete variables this might be more complex (especially when certain values can occur more likely than other values, such that the priors for vakues are unequal)</sup>

What we see when we increase $n$ is that this region becomes more thin and covers a smaller part of the domain.

For the example case you can compute exactly the probability of the event $\hat{X}_n = X$ and show that it decreases to zero.

More generally, we can see intuitively that the image of $f(Y_n)$ get's crowded with more numbers and the area that maps to the correct number becomes smaller. The blue region is like a small strip that runs from $Y_n = -\infty$ to $Y_n = \infty$, is cut into pieces, and placed onto the area. The pieces of the strip get more thin when $n$ increases.

Comment: I don't see that the probability approaches 0.5 even at the edge: if distinguishing $x_0$ and $x_m$ for some $m\to\infty$ but $md\to 0$ is hard,  the probability will not be much higher than $1/m$

Comment: @ThomasLumley if we have a discrete uniform distribution, then we will estimate $\hat{X}_n = 1$ for any $Y_n > 1$. The probability that this happens, *conditional* on ${X}_n = 1$ is 0.5. However, the culprit is indeed that this condition happens with only a small probability.